# Encrypt in ActionScript3 and Decrypt in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, encryption

I need to send data from flash to the server, so I'm looking for a flash ActionScript 3.0 script that will encrypt a text and a C# .net script that decrypt the text.

Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the as3corelib crypto package:
http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/crypto/?r=49

And .NET has it's own cryptography namespace too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Comment: The problem is that I can not find 2 scripts that will work together... I'm tring to use the Rijndael encryption but the AS3 encryption give me a total different encrypt the the C# encryption. Can some one help me with a working codes ???

Comment: what is it you are trying to do ? Encrypt in AS3, then send to C# and decrypt ?
In any case I don't see why it wouldnt work, if the scripts are correct and you use the correct keys too, it should work, I've done this before in AS3 with PHP using md5.