# Encryption between C# and ActionScript 2

Tags: c#, actionscript-2, encryption-symmetric

I'm trying to send encrypted data from a flash ( Action Script 2.0) to decrypt it in C#

So far I've found [this post](http://ryoushin.com/cmerighi/en-us/42,2007-03-02/AES-Rijndael_with_ActionScript_and_ASP_Net.aspx) (Link opens in Chrome, Opera and Safari. Doesn't work in IE nor Firefox)
There's also this question: [Encrypt in ActionScript3 and Decrypt in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308781/encrypt-in-actionscript3-and-decrypt-in-asp-net-c)

But both only work in ActionScript 3

Do you know an API to do this on Action Script 2 ?

Comment: Both of your links point to "http://google/".  Unless Chrome, Opera and Safari have developed telepathy (you never know.  I expect Google to have that working any day) I doubt they will be able to open these links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the [first link](http://ryoushin.com/cmerighi/en-us/42,2007-03-02/AES-Rijndael_with_ActionScript_and_ASP_Net.aspx) indeed works with ActionScript 2.0

There's also code on how to do exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know why/what you intend to encypt. I'm fairly confident that you're probably barking up the wrong tree. It's common knowlege that ActionScript is *very easily* decompiled and your encryption efforts will be wide open for all to see. While this may not be a problem, if you really need encryption and end-to-end security, use HTTPS, not some home-brewed means of securely communicating data.

Comment: We are using [SWF Encrypt](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/) to obfuscate the .swf. Is it enough to protect the potential symmetric key ?

Comment: No. Most definitely not. If the client holds the key to decrypt the data, then this is bad. By definition, swf encrypt is actually only obfuscation. The client needs to know how to decrypt the swf to run it. It would be easy to get the key and decrypt the data. If you must go this route, public key encryption is the only sane way.